# continous integration with just Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005, continuous-integration

any hints on how to start CI with just VS2005 without TFS?

will hudson be able to build VS2005?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) and [CruiseControl.NET](http://ccnet.thoughtworks.com/) can both do this (as well as anything else that can run, say, [NAnt](http://nant.sourceforge.net/)). Using NAnt, you write a script that builds your project. You can have NAnt call MSBuild (via [NAntContrib](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/) I think) and it all works quite beautifully.

Comment: CC.net can also call msbuild directly

Comment: gregmac: Fair enough. Generally I write a NAnt script to do the build as there are other interesting things to do.

Answer (score 1):

Have you possibly looked at TeamCity? There is a free version that allows for up to 20 projects.